# SBCL Note: type assertion too complex to check

Tags: types, common-lisp, sbcl

Having trouble deciphering an SBCL compiler message:

```
; in: DEFUN PURIFY-FILE
;     (DEFUN DEPENDENCIES::PURIFY-FILE (DEPENDENCIES::FILE)
;       "Transforms problematic symbols to benign NIL in file, before reading.
;      Returns a string of altered file content."
;       (LET ((DEPENDENCIES::FILE-STRING
;              (ALEXANDRIA:READ-FILE-INTO-STRING DEPENDENCIES::FILE))
;             (DEPENDENCIES::MODIFIED-FILE-STRING ""))
;         (SETF DEPENDENCIES::MODIFIED-FILE-STRING
;                 (CL-PPCRE:REGEX-REPLACE-ALL "[ trn]'[A-Za-z0-9!@$%&*_+:=<.>/?-]+"
;                                             DEPENDENCIES::FILE-STRING " NIL"))
;         (CL-PPCRE:REGEX-REPLACE-ALL
;          "[(][qQ][uU][oO][tT][eE][ trn]+[A-Za-z0-9!@$%&*_+:=<.>/?-]+[)]"
;          DEPENDENCIES::MODIFIED-FILE-STRING "NIL")))
; --> PROGN SB-IMPL::%DEFUN SB-IMPL::%DEFUN SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA
; ==>
;   #'(SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA DEPENDENCIES::PURIFY-FILE
;         (DEPENDENCIES::FILE)
;       (DECLARE (SB-C::TOP-LEVEL-FORM))
;       "Transforms problematic symbols to benign NIL in file, before reading.
;    Returns a string of altered file content."
;       (BLOCK DEPENDENCIES::PURIFY-FILE
;         (LET ((DEPENDENCIES::FILE-STRING #)
;               (DEPENDENCIES::MODIFIED-FILE-STRING ""))
;           (SETF DEPENDENCIES::MODIFIED-FILE-STRING #)
;           (CL-PPCRE:REGEX-REPLACE-ALL
;            "[(][qQ][uU][oO][tT][eE][ trn]+[A-Za-z0-9!@$%&*_+:=<.>/?-]+[)]"
;            DEPENDENCIES::MODIFIED-FILE-STRING "NIL"))))
;
; note: type assertion too complex to check:
; (VALUES STRING &OPTIONAL BOOLEAN &REST T).
```

My specification for this function is
`(declaim (ftype (function (pathname) (values string (member NIL T))) purify-file))`

Is it something about `CL-PPCRE:REGEX-REPLACE-ALL` returning multiple values? If so, how do you use `ftype` to specify the type of all multiple values--in this case string & NIL or T? Thanks.

Comment: I think it just means that it can't do compile-time type checking to verify that the function always returns that type. It's probably not something to worry about.

Comment: @Barmer, The message specifically seems to say my specification of the return values is a problem. Not sure how to read the hyperspec on this.

Comment: This is not in the hyperspec. It just defines the meaning of type declarations, it doesn't say anything about what implementations do with them.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the typespec `(values string (member NIL T))` is too complex for SBCL, as the message indicates. Changing the typespec to `(values t t)` works.

Comment: Have you tried `(values string boolean)`: that's the same as `(values string (member nil t))`.  In either case I'd leave the typespec and let the compiler complain: for a human reading the code `(values string boolean)` is a *lot* more helpful than `(values t t)`.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately `(values string boolean)` is also too complex. However, a typespec like `(values list list)` is OK.